# hide userform to printer in VBA

Tags: vba, printing, userform

I have this problem with a device I'm trying to program:

I needed to add a "Print" button to a userform, which would have to print the screen image. I managed to build the userform, to add the button and finally to find the built-in VBA command that will print what the device screen shows.

Of course I have no use for my userform to show up in my prints, but no matter what I can't hide it to my printer.

I tried:

```
Userform.hide
Userform.zoom = 10
Userform.visible = false
```

But none of these seem to work.

Comment: It would help if you told us what application you are running this in, provide some more code (where is this running?) and gave your form a sensible name. (UserForm can be the Class name).

Comment: I'm running it in a network analyzer, the UserForm (which is really simple) is built as a "toolbar" to select traces, set scale and so on... So it's really not important the main application, since it just starts the UserForm. The "Print" button has nothing to do with the others basically.
"UserForm"'s real name is obviously not "UserForm", but "Toolbar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the userform outside the screen using the "Move" command:

```
Userform.move right,down
```